# Is decomposition of a semisimple Lie algebra unique?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

A semisimple Lie algebra is defined to be the sum of simple Lie algebras. But is this decomposition to simple Lie algebras unique? If not can you give an example?

Comment: Yes, it is unique (up to order and so on). Where did you see it defined like this? Usually it is defined differently.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I though it was the standard way to define semisimple Lie algebras.

Comment: Usually (over the complex numbers) it is defined by the radical being trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_Lie_algebra),  a Lie algebra is called *semisimple* if it is a direct sum of simple Lie algebras (and a Lie algebra is called *simple* if its adjoint representation is irreducible, i.e., if it has no proper ideal).
The decomposition $L=L_1\oplus \cdots \oplus L_n$ is unique up to permutations of the summands. Indeed, the simple ideals $L_i$ are uniquely determined by $L$, and we have $[L_i,L_j]\subseteq I_i\cap I_j=0$.